# Problems with the use of GDI+

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+

I'm implementing a thumbnail extension on Windows.

I'm trying to convert a picture to a bitmap using GDI+. There is a problem with the use of GDI+ that has bothered me for a long time.

Consider the following two function implementations:

```
HRESULT ThumbnailProvider::getWithGDI(LPCWSTR wpath, HBITMAP* hBitmap)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput input_;
    ULONG_PTR token_;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token_, &input_, NULL);

    std::unique_ptr<gdi::Bitmap> bitmap(Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(wpath));
    if (!bitmap) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    Gdiplus::Status status = bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, hBitmap);
    if (status != Gdiplus::Ok) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token_);

    return S_OK;
}
```

```
class GDIInit {
public:
    GDIInit() {
        gdi::GdiplusStartup(&token_, &input_, NULL);
    }

    ~GDIInit() {
        gdi::GdiplusShutdown(token_);
    }

private:
    gdi::GdiplusStartupInput input_;
    ULONG_PTR token_;
};

HRESULT ThumbnailProvider::getWithGDI(LPCWSTR wpath, HBITMAP* hBitmap)
{
    GDIInit gdiInit;

    std::unique_ptr<gdi::Bitmap> bitmap(Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(wpath));
    if (!bitmap) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    Gdiplus::Status status = bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, hBitmap);
    if (status != Gdiplus::Ok) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

The first function can convert the image under the specified path to a bitmap normally, but the second one does not convert the picture to a bitmap without errors.

All I can see is whether the initialization of GDI+ is called in the constructor.

Is this a problem with GDI+ itself, or the use of C++? Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Generally, GDI Startup/Shutdown should occur in WinMain. Additionally, GDI+ is obsolete, you can use Direct2D/WIC.

Comment: `GdiplusStartup()` can fail, and neither version checks for that. Adding error reporting would be a first step towards diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Initializing GDI+ locally, close to the code where it is actually used, works perfectly fine. This is even listed as one supported technique in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup#remarks).  _"Call GdiplusStartup and GdiplusShutdown in each of your functions that make GDI+ calls."_

Comment: Hello @IInspectable, thanks for the reply, I will try to get the return value.

Comment: Hello, I tried to get the return value, `GdiplusStartup()` returned ok, and `GetLastError()` returned 0. The API call should be successful.

Comment: Not that it makes a difference, but GDI+ doesn't set the last error code, so calling `GetLastError()` returns a meaningless value. The return value is the "extended" error code.

Comment: You must call `GdiplusStartup` before you create any GDI+ objects, and you must delete all of your GDI+ objects (or have them go out of scope) before you call `GdiplusShutdown`.